# Spyder Shortcuts to find and open file?

Tags: python, emacs, shortcut, spyder

I was an Emacs user and I used to find and open files with shortcuts `Ctrl + x + f`

Now my Python IDE is Spyder so I'm wondering if there is an equivalent command?

I have tried `Ctrl + N` and `Ctrl +` O but both returns a window which I need to use the mouse to select by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as sophisticate as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Spyder but you can use one of our IPython consoles along with our owm version of the `%edit` magic to navigate the file system like you'd do in a regular terminal and open files with it.

This is an example (in Linux)

```
In [1]: %edit /home/<Tab>
```

(where `<Tab>` means pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) will show you a widget with these completions (in my case)

```
carlos/
lost+found/
```

Then you can end up with `%edit /home/carlos/foo.py` and after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> `foo.py` will be opened in the Editor (if it exists, of course).

*Additional Notes*:

1. You can use the `%cd` magic to change your current working directory in an IPython console.
2. After you open Spyder, the initial `cwd` is the one shown in our working directory toolbar (usually placed above our Object Inspector).

Comment: Thanks for your information, Im working with windows 7.. TBH Im not getting your method, but let me try first.

Comment: Mmhh Let me know how that goes because most probably this method won't work too well on Windows.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba : Thank you, this works on Linux in combination with ```Ctrl-Shift-I``` to focus on the current IPython-Console. Also works for hidden files: ```%edit ./.gitignore```. However I am used to other editors which support the combination ```Ctrl-O``` to open a file search dialogue. Then hitting enter allowed me to open the file directly. This would be nice to have in Spyder. Thank you for your work!

Answer (score 0):

I use the File Explorer window in Spyder, I find it really handy.